# Alexa nodejs device address api

Tags: node.js, api, https, alexa-skills-kit

I am learning the Alexa Skill kit and making a simple skill to implement the Alexa device address api. However when I test the code on the AWS platform it return "null" as the response and in the log i got :

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 443 }
```

(Not all the info in the log but I think it is the part which caused the issue)

And here's my code:

```
function locationIntent(context,callback) {
var cardTitle = 'Location';
var deviceId = context.context.System.device.deviceId;
var accessToken = context.context.System.apiAccessToken;
var endpoint = context.context.System.apiEndpoint;
var url = endpoint+"/v1/devices/"+deviceId+"/settings/address";
var options = {
    Host: "api.amazonalexa.com",
    Endpoint:"/v1/devices/"+deviceId+"/settings/address",
    Authorization: "Bearer" +accessToken
      };  

getLocation(options,function(rep,err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
         var speechOutput = "Your adress is "+rep.addressLine1;
         var repromptText = speechOutput;
         var shouldEndSession = true;
         callback({},
            buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
            }});
}
function getLocation(options,callback){
https.get(options,function(res){
    var body = '';
    res.on('data',function(chunk){
        body+=chunk;
    });

    res.on('end',function(){
        var result = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(result);
        try{
        callback(result);
    }catch(e){
        console.log("error\n"+e);
        callback("Something is wrong");
    }
    });
}).on('error',function(e){
    console.log("error in api:"+e);
    callback('',e);
});
}
```

So I really would like to know what's the problem in my code. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Just a guess but since the port is 443, try using `https.get` instead of `http`.

Comment: Tried but nothing changes, but still thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`https.get(options, ...` and in options I see you have `Host: "api.amazonalexa.com",` so you are trying to connect to that, right?

But I see it's actually attempting to connect to `127.0.0.1`?

Is it possible you have made any changes in your hosts file and mapped `api.amazonalexa.com` to `127.0.0.1`?

Or maybe your DNS server is doing that?

Can you try to run the following command in your command prompt `nslookup api.amazonalexa.com` and see what it returns?

---

**LE:**

See here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback `Host` should be lowercase `host`. If you put it uppercase it will not use it and default to `localhost` which is `127.0.0.1` as in your error. Also it says that `hostname is preferred over host` so use that name. `Endpoint` doesn't even exists. It should be `path`. `Authorization` should be `auth`. Read the documentation and examples from there and it should work.

Comment: >Server: 127.0.1.1
>Address: 127.0.1.1#53
>Non-authoritative answer:
>Name: api.amazonalexa.com
>Address: 54.239.28.187

Comment: Sorry I tried to make the comment more properly but I'm still learning...

Comment: It resolves to `54.239.28.187` so DNS seems to be ok. Read my answer above which I have updated as it seems that is the problem.